# How do you return html text and a ggplot from a function in R?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, quarto

The following code works as intended, but I have to call the text and plot separately from outside the custom function. I would rather return both of them directly from the function. Additionally - and perhaps unrelated - I'm rendering this in a quarto document and would prefer not to have to call `#| results: asis` from the code chunk.

````
```{r the-kitchen-sink}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false

library(fontawesome)
library(gt)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)

# Demonstrating how to combine variables, text and icons to a fake title
# Dummy variables
text1 <- "Chart 1"
text2 <- "Chart 2"

icon_function <- function(choose_one){

  if (choose_one == "yes") {
      icon_text <- glue::glue(fontawesome::fa(name ='chart-line',
                                              fill = 'darkblue',
                                              prefer_type = 'solid'
                                              ),
                              "<span style='font-size:11pt; font-family: \"Arial\"'> ",
                              text1, " + ", text2,
                              "</span> ",
                              fontawesome::fa(name ='chart-column',
                                              fill = 'grey',
                                              prefer_type = 'solid'
                                              )
                    )

      p <- tibble(group = c('A','B'),
                  amount = c(10,15)
                  )|>
        ggplot() +
        geom_col(aes(x=group, y = amount)) +
        theme_minimal()

  } else {
    icon_text <- glue::glue("Why didn't you choose 'yes'? ",
                            fontawesome::fa(name ='thumbs-down',
                                            fill = 'red',
                                            prefer_type = 'solid'
                                            )
                            )

  }

  html_text <- gt::html(icon_text)

  mylist <- list("mytext" = html_text,
                 "myplot" = p)

  return(mylist)
  
}

mychart <- icon_function("yes")

#Can these output in the function?
mychart$mytext
mychart$myplot
```
````

Comment: I think you want to call the function once and have both the `$mytext` displayed textually and the `$myplot` shown as a graphic, is that right? If so, is there a reason you can't have this code block end with `mychart$mytext`, and then start a new code block that contains just `mychart$myplot`?

Comment: Yes. I want to call the function once and return two outputs or blocks or chunks… but not sure how to approach.

Comment: Try with `cat(icon_text)` and `return(p)` from the function and call the function once! But you would need `result: asis`.

Comment: Almost! It returns both but seem like `cat()` is having issues. The text is on a new line below the first icon and ` ::: {.cell-output-display}` is appended to the end.

Comment: The R `qreport` package goes to a lot of trouble to do things like this.  One example is `maketabs(x)` which makes `Quarto` tabs from a `list()` `x` where the tab names are the list element names.